# is driver.getContextHandles() or driver.context() removed in Selenium4 as these methods are coming for Appium driver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, android-webview, appium, hybrid-mobile-app

Is driver.getContextHandles()  or driver.context() removed in Selenium4 as these methods are coming for Appium driver?
I am Using Selenium 4.1.1 and JavaClient- 8.0.0-beta2.

Facing issue to find element while running a test in Hybrind app.
Scenario
A Web view is opening in App post click of an icon. Element not found exception is coming whereas element is uniquely found/identified in Chrome.

Any suggestions in this will help to procced further.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Regarding the question about `driver.context()`**

This moved to `io.appium.java_client.remote.SupportsContextSwitching` interface which also includes the default implementation.

In your tests if you're using `AppiumDriver`, just cast the driver, like:

```
io.appium.java_client.remote.SupportsContextSwitching

((SupportsContextSwitching) driver).getContextHandles();
```

**NOTE:** To have this work without `ClassCastException`, the driver initially should be created as `AndroidDriver` or `IOSDriver`, e.g.:

```
BaseOptions options = new UiAutomator2Options().setAutoGrantPermissions(true);
AppiumDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), options);
```

**More Details**

I mention this, because `driver.context()` is a special case of a larger context.

There are a lot of changes in appium java client version 8 from version 7.

One of them: A lot of platform-specific and not defined by W3C WebDriver standard methods moved out to additional interfaces.

So pure `AppiumDriver` doesn't have this methods.

But if we look throught the code, e.g. to `AndroidDriver`, we see it implements 20+ additional interfaces:

```
public class AndroidDriver extends AppiumDriver implements
        PressesKey,
        SupportsRotation,
        SupportsContextSwitching,
        SupportsLocation,
        PerformsTouchActions,
        HidesKeyboard,
        HasDeviceTime,
        ...
```

and the same for `IOSDriver`.

If you cannot find some method in `AppiumDriver`, try to go throught the interfaces, which `AndroidDriver`/ `IOSDriver` are implementing.

Comment: Thx Max. I tried below code based on the comments post landing on web page: But not working. Set<String> contextNames = ((SupportsContextSwitching)driver).getContextHandles(); 
   for (String contextName : contextNames) 
   {System.out.println("Available Context"+contextName); }
  wdriver = ((SupportsContextSwitching) driver).context("WEBVIEW_com.crmnextmobile.crmnextofflineplay");

  WebElement textbox = wdriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@data-tvid='TV_View_ctrl']"));
  textbox.sendKeys("abc");
  System.out.println("After Send Keys");

Comment: Getting exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: class io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver cannot be cast to class io.appium.java_client.remote.SupportsContextSwitching (io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver and io.appium.java_client.remote.SupportsContextSwitching are in unnamed module of loader 'app')

Comment: @mittalri I've checked and reproduced this. This appeared if the driver was launched as `AppiumDriver driver = new AppiumDriver(...)`. You have to use `AppiumDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(...)` or  `AppiumDriver driver = new IOSDriver(...)` to avoid `ClassCastException`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thx Again. I tried to use Android driver instead of Appium driver. Post my last comment about class cast exception. Context switch was happening. I will try ur method as well. AppiumDriver driver = new AndroidDriver();